# Change text on mouse hover event

Tags: vb.net

I have a Rich text box having a translation of English paragraph to pig Latin and I need when hovering on any word in this text box the word changes temporarily to its original and to be highlighted at the same time.

So, I'm taking it step by step now the first step is to get the index of the character that is at the location of the mouse and then get the character of the index. but unfortunately the first step is not working :(. here is the code.

```
Private Sub TransRTBox_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TransRTBox.MouseMove

    GetWordUnderMouse(TransRTBox, e.Location.X, e.Location.Y)

End Sub

Friend Sub GetWordUnderMouse(ByRef Rtf As System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, x As Integer, y As Integer)


    Dim point As New Point(x, y)
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim ltr As String

    point.X = x
    point.Y = y
    pos = Rtf.GetCharIndexFromPosition(point)
    ltr = Rtf.Text.Chars(pos)

    MessageBox.Show(ltr)
End Sub
```

the problem is that it always returns the first letter and the pos always equal to 0 no matter where the mouse points or hover, can any one help me in that??

Comment: You can not debug this code with a `MessageBox`. You need `Console.WriteLine("Position " & pos)`. However your code is fine. `Dim point As Point` is correct. No need for the *new* keyword.

Comment: If you use `Dim point As New Point(x, y)` you don't need `point.X = x and point.Y = y`

Answer (score -1):

You need to say `Dim point As New Point(x,y)` because the point is not being instantiated